# Adding Multiple UIButton in UIView in Different Y Position

Tags: objective-c, uiview, xamarin.ios, uibutton

I know how to add UIButton to a UIView programmatically. But I'm stuck in adding the UIButton in the new YPosition after a certain number of UIButtons are added in the previous YPosition.

Here is my case:

- Number of UIButtons to be added comes from NSArray - Let's take 20
- UIView is already added in the UIViewController - Let's call
  'buttonView'
- I'm creating UIButton using the loop (up to 20). I have set the
  buttonWidth as 70 and buttonHeight as 45
- I'm getting the screen size and dividing this by the buttonWith, so
  as to calculate the number of items that can be accommodated per line
  or per Y position.
- If the screen width is 414, then 414/70 = ~5.9 and I'm taking it as
- First 5 UIButton's YPosition as 0 and XPosition starts from 0 and adding buttonWidth for subsequent buttons.
- Next 5 UIButtons (6-10) should have the new YPosition as 1-5 UIButton
  Yposition(0)+buttonHeight(45)+somespace(10)= 55 and XPostion should 
  start with 0.
- For the next set of UIButtons(11-15), the YPosition should be
  Yposition(55)+buttonHeight(45)+somespace(10)= 100 and XPosition 
  starts with 0

How to achieve this? Below is my code

```
xPos = 8.0f; 
yPos = 0.0f;
totalSlots =timeslots.Count - //Total Number UIButtons to be creted
buttonWidth = 70;
buttonHeight = 45;
buttonViewWidth = this.view.frame.size.width // I'm getting the screen
buttonPerLine = scrollViewWidth / (buttonWidth + 10); // This calculates no.of.buttons per line/Y Position. I'm rounding off as said before
numberOfLine = totalSlots / buttonPerLine // This gives how many lines needed

for (int i = 0; i < totalSlots; i++)
                        {
timeSlotbtn[i] = new UIButton();
                        timeSlotbtn[i] = new UIButton();
                        timeSlotbtn[i].Frame = new CGRect(xPos, yPos, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
                        timeSlotbtn[i].SetTitle(buttonText, UIControlState.Normal);
                        timeSlotbtn[i].Layer.BorderWidth = 2.0f;
                        timeSlotbtn[i].Layer.CornerRadius = 3;
                        timeSlotbtn[i].Tag = i;
                        timeSlotbtn[i].TitleLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeue-bold", 14.0f);


                xPos = timeSlotbtn[i].Frame.Location.X + buttonWidth + buttonSpace;
                timeslotScrollView.AddSubview(timeSlotbtn[i]);
}
```

Pleas be noted the above code is written in Xamarin.iOS. If you know the solution, then probably you can write in Objective-c. Anyhow, the logic should be same.

Comment: I solved this. I have updated the code in case if someone is looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
            int buttonWidth = 65;
            int buttonSpace = 5;
            int buttonHeight = 30;
            int totalSlots = timeslots.Count;
            nfloat screenSize = firstViewController.screenSize;
            nfloat buttonPerLine = screenSize / (buttonWidth + buttonSpace );
            int roundedButtonPerLine = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(buttonPerLine));
            nfloat totalLines = totalSlots / buttonPerLine;
            int roundedTotalLines = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(totalLines));
            nfloat determineXPosition = (screenSize - (8 + (buttonWidth * roundedButtonPerLine) + (buttonSpace*(roundedButtonPerLine-1))))/2;
            nfloat xPos;
            if (roundedTotalLines > 1)
            {
                 xPos = determineXPosition;
            }
            else
            {
                 xPos = 8.0f;
            }

            nfloat yPos = 0.0f;
            int currentLine = 1;
            int loopCount = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < room.timeslots.Count; i++)
            {
                var buttonText = room.timeslots[i].startDate.ConvertDateToStanfordLocalTime();//hour + ":" + minute + "p";
                timeSlotbtn[i] = new UIButton();
                timeSlotbtn[i].Frame = new CGRect(xPos, yPos, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
                timeSlotbtn[i].SetTitle(buttonText, UIControlState.Normal);
                timeSlotbtn[i].Layer.BorderWidth = 2.0f;
                timeSlotbtn[i].Layer.CornerRadius = 3;
                timeSlotbtn[i].Tag = i;
                timeSlotbtn[i].TitleLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeue-bold", 14.0f);

                xPos = timeSlotbtn[i].Frame.Location.X + buttonWidth + buttonSpace;
                timeslotScrollView.AddSubview(timeSlotbtn[i]);


                if (loopCount == roundedButtonPerLine)
                {

                    if (roundedTotalLines > 1)
                    {
                         xPos = determineXPosition;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         xPos = 8.0f;
                    }
                    currentLine++;
                    yPos = timeSlotbtn[i].Frame.Location.Y + buttonHeight + buttonSpace;
                    loopCount = 0;
                }
                loopCount++;
            }
```